# Why is ARC deallocating my object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a view controller I'm storing into a mutable array.

```
- (void)pushViewController:(KAViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.viewControllers addObject:viewController];

    if (self.count == 0)
        [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    else 
        [self transitionFromView:self.currentViewController.view toView:viewController.view];
}
```

The array (viewControllers) is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
```

The view has a button, and when I click on it I get the following message:

> [KAGameInfoViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]:
>   message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e6e900

I've confirmed that 0x6e6e900 is the address to my view controller.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Turning off ARC fixing the problem.

Comment: What is the `self.count` property for?

Comment: I am assuming all of this code is part of your `KAGameInfoViewController` class. Does it have an ivar called `count`? If not then `if (self.count ==0)` might be an issue.

Comment: Turning off ARC may not be a great solution, as it likely masks an allocation issue with your code.

Comment: @adamjansch agreed. I just turned if off to see if it was causing the problem.

Comment: self.count simply returns the count of viewControllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `self.viewControllers` is nil because you forgot to do:

```
self.viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

anywhere.

Comment: Hahaha I plead temporary absence of intelligence :/